# Canvas.children: System.ArgumentException: 'Specified index is already in use. Disconnect the Visual child at the specified index first.'

Tags: c#, wpf

At the moment I am trying to assing a new value to one of canvas' children in wpf and it throws the exeption above I have the following code which I think is relavent:

```
var val = comps[0].GetComponent();
c.Children[comps[0].Index] = val;
```

Intrestingly the problem self-resolves when I do this:

```
var val = comps[0].GetComponent();
c.Children.RemoveAt(comps[0].Index);
c.Children.Insert(comps[0].Index, val);
```

but I want to understand whats happening and if there is a more efficient way of preventing the exeption

Comment: Your version using RemoveAt (int) and Insert (int, object) is correct for the given problem statement.
But in general for the Solution, it might be worth using an ItemsControl with a panel for Canvas items and a given ItemTemplate.
This can greatly simplify the code and improve the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that the `System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection` class explicitly checks whether the index in the collection that you are trying to assign a new value to is already in use and if it is, it throws an `ArgumentException`. Look at line 379 in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/VisualCollection.cs,1bafd2a0e01f3a5c):

```
if (child != null)
{
    throw new System.ArgumentException(SR.Get(SRID.VisualCollection_EntryInUse));
}
```

So, as you already do, you should explicitly check if there is an element at the index and remove it before you try to insert a new item:

```
int index = 0;
if (canvas.Children.Count > index)
{
    canvas.Children.Remove(canvas.Children[index]);
}
canvas.Children.Insert(index, val);
```

Comment: @мм8, IMHO, plus the index does not need to be done.
Think about what will happen if there are five elements and you need to replace the fourth.
The condition will not be true and an insert will occur instead of replacement.

Comment: And instead of Remove (object) it is better to use RemoveAt (int).

Comment: @EldHasp: You are right +1 in unnecessary. I edited my answer. Your second comment is not true though.

Comment: @мм8, Could you explain why you think so?
My reasoning is as follows: Remove (object) performs a linear search for an equivalent item. And the first equivalent element will be removed.
RemoveAt (int) without searching, immediately removes the element at the specified index.
This is faster. And besides, if there are several equivalents in the collection, there will be no collisions.

Comment: `RemoveAt` basically looks up the item twice before calling `InternalRemove`. I haven't mesaured which method that is the fastest though. It shouldn't make any difference as this is not a performance issue.